# DirectoryEntry is not getting even add the namespace System.DirectoryServices?

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

In my web app I want to create an object of type `DirectoryEntry`.. but it is not generated on the `.aspx.cs` file even though I added the namespace and my `web.config` contains

```
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

in the `<assemblies>` section.

What will be the reason ? please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you should add reference to System.DirectoryServices.dll?

Comment: how is it ? @DreamChild

Answer (score 0):

On Visual studio, right click your project. choice add reference , choice on .net tab, and add System.DirectoryServices reference.

Comment: es i have already added it @Yan Zhao